# Check on url with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, url

How can I get the URL of the current page? I have a contact form that opens by clicking a button. When you submit the form, the page is doing a page refresh. The URL of the page is than:

```
http://remarkit.mikevierwind.nl/#wpcf7-f51-t1-o1
```

How can I check with JavaScript or jQuery on the URL, so that when the page have that URL I can open the contact form?

Comment: Yeah, it is a .NET page refresh

Comment: You mean ASP.NET page postback?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to look at the location in general you look at:

```
window.location.href
```

If you want to look at the hash `#` value:

```
window.location.hash
```

See [`window.location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location) in the MDN for documentation.

Comment: @meagar [help....](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11759747/check-on-url-with-javascript/11760049#comment15613207_11759786) :-(

Answer (score 1):

You can get the current url of a page using:  `document.URL` or `window.location.href`

Answer (score 0):

i prefer this way to look at url`s:

```
var link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = window.location;

    link.protocol;
    link.hostname;
    link.pathname;
    link.search;
    link.hash;     //gives you "#wpcf7-f51-t1-o1" for your example
    link.host;
```

it`s a simple and smart way i think (maybe you also).
Hope it helps.

Comment: Ummmm.... you can get all that information from `window.location`. There is no need to add it to an anchor.

Comment: yes, but with this way you can also add relative url`s to href or let href complete empty. the browser will set it to a full URL  https://gist.github.com/2428561

Comment: [Like this for example?](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/4756770#4756770) ^_^

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you supply at least the markup for your question.

But what I was able to understand, you have a page. In that you have a button, and you want to open a form on the click of that button. What do you want to do on the submit of the form? Or is that action not relevant to the question right now?

If you want to open a form on the click of a button, then you can use the `window.open` command to open it in a popup window. (you will need the popup plugin).

```
$("#id_of_button").on("click",function(){
  window.open("contact.html");
});
```

Put the form in contact.html and do whatever you want to do on submit from there.

Secondly, why do you want to check the URL when all you want to do is open a form on the click of a button? that URL will not be there unless anyone clicks on the button, or enters it manually (which, most probably, you wouldn't want).